# Rewriting an expression with a radical in the numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a (seemingly) easy algebra question, on which I'm quite stuck. It's from a calculus book (Calculus Made Easy - Silvanus Thompson), in which the author rewrites the expression:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x}$$

to:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$

I'm stumped on which steps to take to arrive at the latter expression from the first. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Difference of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the difference of two squares to find:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)}}{1+x} = \frac{\sqrt{1-x} \sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1+x}}$$

Can you continue?

The domain is $-1 < x ≤ -1, x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, that cleared it up! I often overlook that 1 can always be squared. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x}
=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{(1+x)^2}}
=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x)^2}}
=\sqrt{\frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{(1+x)(1+x)}}
$$
assuming $1+x>0$.

Comment: Clear, thank you!